# Count of paths between N points

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to arrive at a formula that will give me the number of distinct paths between a set of discrete points on a map.  I have worked out that I can calculate it using a series of additions:

(N-1) + (N-2) + (N-3) ... + 1

For seven discrete points, the number of paths between them is 21: 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1

For eight it is 28: 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1

That's easy enough, but what if I need the number of distinct paths for, say, 600 discrete points.  Obviously I could start adding them up as:

599 + 598 + 597 ... + 1

But is there some magic formula that would enable me to get the result quickly without having to add them all up, or use a spreadsheet, or write a computer program to calculate it?

Comment: you may try $\binom{n-1}{2}$ or  $\binom{n-2}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed such a magic formula!  In general, we have
$$
1 + 2 + \cdots + (n-1) + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
We can think of this as follows: the average of all values added is $\frac{n+1}2$ (the value of the highest and the lowest).  So, adding this with itself $n$ times should (and does) give us the actual total.  For more on this, look into the [sum of an arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum).

At any rate: for a group of $n$ points, there are $\binom n2 = \frac 12 n(n-1)$ paths between them, where $\binom nr$ is the associated [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Comment: $\frac 12 n(n-1)$ does the trick!  Using a spreadsheet I came up with an actual answer, with n = 600, as 179,700.  Your "at any rate" agrees with it!  Thanks!